# regex for spliting <=lastdate+30d in to array of 5

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to split the following string into substring using regex match function. But it's not splitting the last element. Can anyone point out the mistake I am doing?

```
"<=lastdate+30d".match(/(>=|<=|==|<|>|\!=)|\w+|[-+]|\d|[dhms]/g)

result is ["<=", "lastdate", "+", "30d"]

expected result is ["<=", "lastdate", "+", "30", "d"]
```

Comment: Please Show - what have you tried ?

Comment: "<=lastdate+30d".match(/(>=|<=|==|<|>|\!=)|\w+|[-+]|\d|[dhms]/g)

Comment: @KrunalShah The attempt is included in the post ..?

Comment: It looks like you do not want to handle fractional numbers, since you are not using my suggestion. Try then [`.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|\d+|[^\s\w]+/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/cl8HA8/1)

Comment: Another idea: `s.match(/^([<>!=]=|[=<>])([a-zA-Z]+)(?:([-+])(\d+)([dhms])?)?$/)` - and you will have access to all the groups in the match values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your regex is that `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So, last `30d` is matched by `\w+`.

Use below regex:

```
/(>=|<=|==|<|>|\!=)|[a-z]+|[-+]|\d+|[dhms]/
```

```js
console.log("<=lastdate+30d".match(/(>=|<=|==|<|>|\!=)|[a-z]+|[-+]|\d+|[dhms]/gi));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"<=lastdate+30d".match(/>=|<=|==|<|>|\!=|\d+|\w+|[-+]|[dhms]/g)
```

It is considering 30d a word character,  if you search for numbers first it separates it.